# Collection View layout

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, uicollectionview

Is it possible to create a 3 column newspaper like layout with collection view?

I tried using 3 table views and it works but is very laggy. So if collection views are a native solution I think it's better to use them. Do they fit my task?

The main problem is that all cells are filled from left to right:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

And I need:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think that a collectionview would suit your needs. You will probably have to use a custom layout. Check out "introduction to collectionviews" and "advanced layout with collection views" on the WWDC 2012 videos. By using a custom layout you can order the cells any way you like.

Comment: (I was just about to say the same.) You should also read [Creating Custom Layouts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1) in the "Collection View Programming Guide for iOS"

Comment: thanks, guess Apple developers made relatively easy task a little bit painful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to reorder your data source.

**EDIT:**

```
NSArray *oldArr = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11"];
NSMutableArray *newArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:oldArr.count];

int row = ceilf(oldArr.count / 3.f);
int remainder = oldArr.count % 3;

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    [newArr addObject:[oldArr objectAtIndex:i]];

    if (i == (row - 1) && remainder == 1)
        continue;

    [newArr addObject:[oldArr objectAtIndex:i + row]];

    if (i == (row - 1) && remainder == 2)
        continue;

    [newArr addObject:[oldArr objectAtIndex:i + row * 2]];
}
```

result:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, = > 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, 4, 8
```

formatting print:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11

to

1  5  9
2  6  10
3  7  11
4  8
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

You can by changing the scroll direction to horizontal. That way you'll have it ordered like you want, and scrolling makes the most sense.

If you wanna do that with vertical scrolling, you'll have to write your own subclass of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. But would make the user experience really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've finished with fixing my 3 table view layout. Instead of loading cells from XIB I've created programmatically. This gave me huge increase in performance. Thank you for the answers guys.